# Error while running macro : Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro which works exactly how I want it to. However, I get an error message everytime it runs which is in the title of this question. Here's my code:

```vb
Sub Calculate()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim SourceRange As String
    
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim TargetRange As String
    
    Dim ColumnCount As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim visibleTotal As Long
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CALCULATION")
    
    t = Now()
    
    If Source.Cells("1,") = Empty Then MsgBox "Please check if there is data in Sheet1"
    If Source.Cells("1,") = Empty Then Exit Sub
    
    TargetRow = 2
    ColumnCount = Source.Range("A:K").Columns.Count
    
    For SourceRow = 1 To Source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
        SourceRange = Range(Cells(SourceRow, 1), Cells(SourceRow, ColumnCount)).Address
    
        While Target.Cells(TargetRow, 6).Value <> ""
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        Wend
    
        TargetRange = Range(Cells(TargetRow, 1), Cells(TargetRow, ColumnCount)).Address
    
        Target.Range(TargetRange).Value = Source.Range(SourceRange).Value
    
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
    Next
    
    Target.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    lastRow = Target.Range("A" & Target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set filterRange = Target.Range("A1:K" & lastRow)
    
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Domestic Shares"
    
    Target.Range("M2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
       
    Target.ShowAllData
       
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Foreign Shares"
    
    Target.Range("M3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
       
    Target.ShowAllData
       
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Bonds EUR In"
    
    Target.Range("M4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
       
    Target.ShowAllData
       
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Bonds EUR Out"
    
    Target.Range("M5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
       
    Target.ShowAllData
       
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Own Products AB"
    
    Target.Range("M6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
    
    MsgBox "Elapsed Time in Hrs:Min:Sec :" & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
       
    Target.ShowAllData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Target.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
    
Sub Clear()
    
    Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).ClearContents
    Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("M2:M6").ClearContents
    
End Sub
    
Sub Clear2()
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
    
End Sub
```

I added some lines of code at the start and the end (Application.calculate, application.screenupdating etc) to make the macro run more efficiently. In some of my colleagues' computers excel stops working altogether while this macro runs. Also for context: The amount of data which gets pasted on the sheet named "Sheet1" is about 6000-8000 rows and 34 columns of data.

Comment: At what point in your code does Excel run out of resources.

Comment: The error pops up when i run any of the three subs. After i run the Calculate sub, the data does get pasted from Sheet1 after which it shows the error. So the error message pop ups when i run the macro and when i also simply copy the data from another excel file onto Sheet1.

Comment: Difficult to say anything useful without knowing what's getting calculated and how.

Comment: Its quite simple. It just pastes the data from one sheet to another. Applies some text filters one after the other and then counts the number of rows for each different text filter.

Comment: You have quite a few unqualified Range/Cells calls such as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, Range("$E2:D" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))`   I'd start by making sure those all have a worksheet qualifier.

Comment: Do your sheets contain formulas?  You've set calculation to manual, so nothing should be calculating...

Comment: My sheet only contains one small macro (which is just literally the sum of 5 cells). I just googled about unqualified cells. Should I use the WITH statement to qualify them? I have very limited knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0):

See if this changes anything:

```vb
Sub Calculate()
    
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 11
    
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range 'not string
    Dim Target As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, rw As Range, v, cResult As Range
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim TargetRange As String
    Dim ColumnCount As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filterRange As Range, rngCalc As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim visibleTotal As Long, t
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Source = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = wb.Worksheets("CALCULATION")
    
    t = Now()
    
    If Len(Source.Cells(1).Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please check if there is data in Sheet1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    TargetRow = 2
    'copy source rows to first available slots on Target
    For SourceRow = 1 To Source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        While Len(Target.Cells(TargetRow, 6).Value) > 0
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        Wend
        Target.Cells(TargetRow, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value = _
              Source.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value
    Next
    
    Target.AutoFilterMode = False
    With Target
        Set filterRange = .Range("A1:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    Set cResult = Target.Range("M2").Value
    'you can reduce the repetition using an array here
    For Each v In Array("Domestic Shares", "Foreign Shares", "Bonds EUR In", _
                        "Bonds EUR Out", "Own Products AB")
    
        filterRange.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=v
        Set rngCalc = Target.Range("D2:E" & Target.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        cResult.Value = Application.Subtotal(2, rngCalc)
        Set cResult = cResult.Offset(1, 0) 'next result cell
    
    Next v
    
    MsgBox "Elapsed Time in Hrs:Min:Sec :" & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
       
    Target.ShowAllData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Target.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
    
Sub Clear()
    With Worksheets("CALCULATION")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).ClearContents
        .Range("M2:M6").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
    
Sub Clear2()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
End Sub
```

I'm not entirely clear exactly what you're doing here though, so it might not be exactly right...